# Why am I getting groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException for TRACE?

Tags: grails, logging, groovy, log4j

In groovy file I've imported jars `groovy.util.logging.Log4j` and 
`org.apache.log4j.Level` for using `@Log4j`and I'm setting log level as: **`log.setLevel(Level.TRACE)`** in the constructor.

Now while executing the script I'm getting `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: TRACE for class: org.apache.log4j.Level` but when I replace **TRACE** with **INFO** it executes successfully.

So what will be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you try statically importing the levels `import static org.apache.log4j.Level.*` then set like `log.level = TRACE`

Comment: Which version of `org.apache.log4j` are you using? If you check https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html you can see that `TRACE` is available since: 1.2.12

Comment: I'm using `log4j-1.2.16.jar`, so TRACE is available in this.

Comment: It is not working *Mike W*, showing same issue.

Comment: That sounds like a problem in the project.  If you could share an example which demonstrates the problem, it would likely be trivial to troubleshoot.

Comment: This issue occurs for all groovy files present in the server. @JeffScottBrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use multiple version of log4j in your application?
[log4j-1.2.16.jar & lower to log4j-1.2.12.jar which doesn't support TRACE]
In this case,lower version might have been taken into consideration by your groovy script.If you are executing script in LINUX,append $GROOVY_HOME/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar to $CLASSPATH at the end. This works!!!